# Wordpress Yoast plugin open graph to fetch Avatar from Author Page

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, avatar, author

I'm trying to create a new `og:image` for author avatar when the users sharing their author profile page to Facebook.

I used `wpseo_opengraph_image` filter, but when I share the link for the first time the image not showing and in the second time it comes up!

When I look to the Inspector `<head>` I see `<meta property="og:image" content="http://h">`

This is code I'm using:

```
function custom_author_og_image() {
    if ( is_author ( ) ) {
    $author = get_queried_object();
        $image_attributes = get_avatar_url( $author->user_email, 'full' );
        if ( $image_attributes !== false ) {
            return $image_attributes[0];
        }
    }
}
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_image', 'custom_author_og_image', 10, 0);
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Is there any error message on the browser console the first time you try to open an author page? Does that incomplete `<meta>` property shows only 1 time? Or everytime?

Comment: no i didn't get any errors!

Comment: Any help please